# Compact Metric Problem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

while defining Compact Metric Space in one of book of HL ROYDEN's REAL ANALYSIS statement says:

> If T is collection of open subsets of a metric space X, then the collection F of complements of sets in T is collection of closed sets. Moreover, T is cover if and only if F has empty intersection. Thus, "By de Morgan identities a metric space X is compact if and only if every collection of closed sets with a non empty intersection has a finite sub-collection whose intersection also is nonempty"

firstly, this statement says T is cover if and only if intersection of F is empty, then it goes on saying that X is compact if and only if every collection of closed sets with nonempty intersection has finite sub-collection whose intersection also is nonempty.

Please explain it?.

Comment: The correct statement should be that $X$ is compact if and only if every collection of closed sets with empty intersection has a finite subcollection with empty intersection. It's either a typo or a translation error.

Comment: Or maybe it should read "if every finite subcollection of $F$ has a non-empty intersection then $F$ has a non-empty intersection"? This is the usual way to state compactness in terms of the [finite intersection property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_intersection_property).

Comment: You can see that there is a mistake in the book by considering that in $any$ space $X$, if $C$ is $any$ collection of subsets of $X$ with $\cap C\ne\emptyset$ then there must exist $D\in C$ with $D\ne\emptyset,$ but then $C'=\{D\}$ is a finite sub-collection of $C$ with $\cap C'=D\ne\emptyset.$

Comment: In one of proposition HL ROYDEN says : A metric space X is compact if and only if every collection F of closed subsets of X with finite intersection property(A collection F of sets in X is said to have finite intersection property provided any finite subcollection of F has a nonempty intersection) has non empty intersection. Can you explain this propisition?

Comment: See the end of my answer for that. Plus there is nothing "metric" about this proposition; it holds in all topological spaces.

Comment: Just as a side note, Royden is good book, but also a really horribly edited book. Expect more of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to explain is with de Morgans laws:

$complement(A\cup B) =complement(A)\cap complement(B) $

So if $T$ is a cover of $X$, then

$$ \empty = complement(X) = complement(\cup_{t\in T}A_{t}) = \cap_{t\in T} complement(A_{t})$$

$X$ is compact if an only if every open cover has a finite subcover, thus $X$ is compact if and only if given any such $T$ as above there exists $T'\subset T$ with $T'$ finite so that:

$$ \empty = complement(X) = complement(\cup_{t\in T'}A_{t}) = \cap_{t\in T'} complement(A_{t})$$

Comment: That doesn't explain the incorrect statement that the OP claims to have found in Royden's book. I am sure this is the result of a misquotation.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{F_i \mid i \in I\}$ be a collection of closed sets with empty intersection.

Applying de Morgan:

$$\emptyset = \bigcap_{i \in I} F_i \implies X= \left(\bigcap_{i \in I} F_i\right)^\complement = \bigcup_{i \in I} F_i^\complement$$

so indeed $\{F_i^\complement \mid i \in I\}$ forms an open (the complement of a closed set is open) cover of $X$ and so has a finite subcover (if $X$ is compact), say $F_{j}^\complement, j \in F$ where $F \subseteq I$ is finite, and doing the previous backwards again:

$$X=\bigcup_{j \in F} F_j^\complement \implies \emptyset = \left(\bigcup_{j \in F} F_j^\complement\right)^\complement = \bigcap_{j \in F} F_j$$

so the intersection of the finitely many $F_j, j \in F$ is empty.

This is found in many books in a logically equivalent contrapositive formulation: they call a family of sets such that any finite subfamily has non-empty intersection a family with the FIP (finite intersection property) and then the previous can also be stated as:

> If $X$ is compact and if $\{F_i\mid i \in I\}$ is a family of closed sets with the FIP, then $\bigcap_i F_i \neq \emptyset$,

which looks more "positive", a guarantee that an infinite intersecion is non-empty provided all finite intersections are. But it really comes down to complements, de Morgan and the complementary open cover argument. For, suppose that the intersection of such a FIP closed family were empty, the argument from the beginning then tells us that a finite subfamily of them had an empty intersection too, but this directly contradicts the FIP assumption on the family, so cannot happen. So the intersection is non-empty.